# Icon not display with skycons

Tags: javascript, icons

Hello there I wanna know what I did wrong in my code in my weather app. 
I'm using javascript and here is the code

```
enter code here


 fetch(api)
  .then(Response =>{
       return Response.json();
     })
   .then(data =>{
      const{temperature, summary, icon } = data.currently;
      // set dom elements from api
      temperaturedegree.textContent = temperature ;
      temperaturedescription.textContent = summary;
      locationtimezone.textContent = data.timezone;
      //set icon
      setIcons(icon, document.querySelector(".icon"));
     })
   })
   }
   function setIcons(icon, iconID) {
      const skycons = new Skycons({color :"white"});
      const currentIcon = icon.replace(/-/g, "_").toUpperCase();
      skycons.play();
      return skycons.set(iconID, skycons[currentIcon]);
   }
   });
```

Thanks for telling me what I did wrong.

Comment: Please take time to indent your code, no offense but it hurts to read this.

Comment: sorry dude i'm only a beginner i'm sorry i'm doing the best i could

Comment: No problem, but being a beginner doesn't mean you cannot make a clean post. Really, indenting your code is for you and your readers, it will help you and it can be done automatically in almost every editor.

Comment: yeah thanks i will sorry and thanks for the advice